# Can I deploy an IIS express MVC app with click once?

Tags: clickonce, iis-express

Can I get a clickonce win forms app to also bring with it and install an iis express mvc app? the iis app is going to be responding to local requests only.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a ClickOnce WinForms app. You can package up the MVC application and include it in the deployment. I'm not sure how you're going to install it on the client machine, though. I guess you can just try using Start.Process(path to file).

It will require privileges to install the app on the localhost, though. The ClickOnce application can invoke the install and it will ask the user if they want to elevate permissions. I don't know how you're going to tell if they have IIS or IIS Express installed.